# In Datagridview enter key press selection goes to next row but i want goes to next column?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

In `DataGridView` enter key press selection goes to next row but I want goes to next column? How can fix it?

```
private void textBox1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
{       
   if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
   {
   }
}
```

Comment: `textBox1`? Are you sure it's a correct event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a property named [CurrentCell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentcell(v=vs.110).aspx) in the class `DataGridView`, so you should use it:

```
    private void dataGridView1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            int newRow;
            int newColumn;
            if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == dataGridView1.ColumnCount-1)         // it's a last column, move to next row;
            {
                newRow = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex + 1;
                newColumn = 0;

                if (newRow == dataGridView1.RowCount)
                    return; // ADD new row or RETURN (depends of your purposes..)
            }
            else                // just change current column. row is same
            {
                newRow = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
                newColumn = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex + 1;
            }

            dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[newRow].Cells[newColumn];
        }
    }
```